# Batch ps2pdf fails

Tags: windows, batch-file

I still have not solved why this code which correctly runs through all the sub folders, looking for jpg files to convert to pdf files and compresses them but exits before executing any command after the final ')'. It is definitely due to ps2pdf but can't think of what ps2pdf can be changing. Any ideas?

```
@echo on
set records="C:\Users\john\Documents\0 BDHS Digitised records\Awaiting processing\"
cd %records%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r . %%G in (.) do ( Pushd %%G
If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto:eof
rem merge jpgs to PDF
jpeg2pdf.exe *.jpg -o "%%~nG".pdf
set fname=%%G
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/ebook "%%~nG".pdf "%%~nG"compressed.pdf
popd )

echo Ended
pause
```

Comment: To directly fix your issue, _(not specifically improve your script)_, `ps2pdf` is really `ps2pdf.bat`, which means that in order for your code to continue upon completion of that script, you need to `call` it. Please therefore change it to read `call ps2pdf.bat -dPDFSETTINGS#/ebook "%%~nG.pdf" "%%~nGcompressed.pdf"`.

Comment: Thank you. That is it! Hurrah!

Comment: No problem John. Please feel free to test my 'possibly improved' version in the answer I posted, and provide appropriate feedback..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of your script, with the required `Call` for your `ps2pdf.bat` file.

Before running it, please substitute the correct full paths for your executable utility, `jpeg2pdf.exe`, *(line `14`)*, and script `ps2pdf.bat`, *(line `15`)*. It is not a good idea to rely on modifiable registry or environment variables hence the reason I'm advising their full paths. If those two files will always be located in the directory of this batch file, or relative to it, feel free to use `%~dp0` in designating those paths.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "records=%UserProfile%\Documents\0 BDHS Digitised records\Awaiting processing"

Set "fname="
If Exist "%records%\" (
    For /R "%records%" %%G In (*.jpg) Do (
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If Not "!fname!" == "%%~dpG" (
            EndLocal
            Set "fname=%%~dpG"
            For %%H In ("%%~dpG.") Do (
                Rem Merge JPGs to PDF
                "P:\athTo\EXE\jpeg2pdf.exe" "%%~dpG*.jpg" -o "%%~dpG%%~nxH.pdf"
                Call "P:\athTo\ps2pdf.bat" -dPDFSETTINGS#/ebook "%%~dpG%%~nxH.pdf" "%%~dpG%%~nxHcompressed.pdf"
            )
        ) Else EndLocal
    )
    Echo Ended.
) Else Echo Directory %records% dos not exist.
Pause
```

The example above, has been made more efficient, by only recursing through directories which contain files with `.jpg` extensions.

The script however does not step in an out of directories using `PushD` and `PopD`, as did yours. Whilst this may be a slight improvement efficiency wise, it may bring rise to another issue. As I do not know your utilities, if they only accept limited length commandlines or paths, this version could choke.